# When to use cloud functions for Firebase real time databse?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am not clear with architecture of using Firebase for Android apps. Can you make everything from client side without using Cloud Functions, since it is possible to access database with functions in java. Is it used only for security purposes to restrict client from making problems?

Answer (score 1):

Most functionality can indeed be performed directly from the client-side app, using the Firebase SDK for your application platform. And whenever this is possible, I highly recommend implementing it this way.

But certain types of functionality don't lend themselves well for performing directly from the client. They typically fall into these main categories:

- The operation requires privileged information. For example if you want to send push notifications to your app users, you will need to specify the FCM server key. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a server you control, or in an otherwise trusted environment, such as Cloud Functions. This same reason also applies to things like interacting with payment gateways, and many APIs in the Google Cloud Platform that require server-side API keys.
- The code of the operation itself **is** a privileged operation. For example you'll often find this in games, where you want to validate that the user isn't cheating. If you put this code in your app itself, a malicious user can see it and use it to circumvent your detection. By moving the code into Cloud Functions, the users of the app can't see the code anymore.
- The code requires more "power" (CPU, network, memory, disk space, battery) than you can rely on being available on your user's devices. Since Cloud Functions run in Google data centers, they are always connected to mains power, they have a reliable CPU, a great network, and configurable memory/RAM disk space.

Another advantage is that Cloud Functions are the same for users on any platform that you target. Say you have a complex algorithm that you want the users on Android, iOS, and Web to use. If you implement the algorithm in Cloud Functions you only have to implement it once, and then call it from each platform, instead of having to implement the algorithm for each one.

I also recommend that you check out the [list of use-cases in the Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases).